# KL divergence between GPs undefined?

Tags: stochastic-processes, gaussian-process, kullback-leibler, variational-bayes

In Theorem 1 in [Sun et al, *Functional Variational Bayesian Neural Networks*, 2019](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.05779), the authors state the the KL divergence between stochastic processes in the supremum over KL divergence between vectors each element of which is sampled from the respective process, meaning

\begin{equation}
 KL(f \| g) = \sup_{n \in N, x_1, …, x_n \in X} KL([ f(x_1).. f(x_n)]\ \|\ [g(x_1).. g(x_n) ]).
\end{equation}

I constructed a simple example for which it doesn't make sense, any pointers on where it's wrong (or violates implicit assumptions in the paper) appreciated.

Take $g \sim GP(0, k)$, $f \sim GP(0, 2k)$, two zero-mean Gaussian processes; the kernel of g is two times the kernel of g. The kernel k can be arbitrary. The KL divergence between vectors is then the KL divergence between multivariate Gaussians, and takes the well-known form (remember that we assumed zero means)

\begin{equation}
    KL([ f(x_1).. f(x_n)]\ \|\ [g(x_1).. g(x_n) ]) = \frac{1}{2} \left( \mathrm{Tr} \left[ \Sigma_2^{-1}   \Sigma_1 \right]  - \log \left[\det  \Sigma_1 / \det  \Sigma_2\right]  - n \right)
\end{equation}

for $\Sigma_1$ the Gram matrix of $2k$ evaluated on $x_1, \dots, x_n$, and $\Sigma_2$ the Gram matrix of $k$ evaluated on $x_1, \dots, x_n$. Then $2\Sigma_2=\Sigma_1$, and we can simplify further,

\begin{equation}
    KL([ f(x_1).. f(x_n)]\ \|\ [g(x_1).. g(x_n) ]) = \frac{1}{2} \left( 2n  - n \log 2 - n \right) = \frac{n(1- \log 2)}{2}.
\end{equation}

The supremum of this is infinity. That would imply the KL between two GPs, with arbitrary kernels, is not defined, which seems unlikely! What's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The KL-divergence is not undefined, it really is infinite.  There are very limited settings under which two Gaussian processes are mutually absolutely continuous